# Is there an area in Los Angeles that is known for selling used photography equipment?

Tags: shopping, photography, los-angeles

Some big cities (Paris, Tokyo) have a street or neighborhood with a concentration of camera and photography equipment stores. Is there such an area in Los Angeles ?

To be specific I'm not looking for electronics stores, I'm interested in places selling old analog cameras and lenses that can be found reasonably close to each other as I'll be shopping on foot.

Comment: Just so you don't feel like the question is being ignored, I *suspect* the answer is likely "no, there isn't"... you might find pawn shops with a fair amount of this stuff, but more likely spread out in the San Fernando Valley.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar question was asked (way back in 2009) by David Dennis on [photo.net](http://photo.net/casual-conversations-forum/00Ryya).

There there are *some* suggestions for specific shops (that might no longer exist!) but the general opinion seems to be "no chance". For example:

> I haven't known a decent place for used camera equipment in Los Angeles for many years.
>
> Last time I was at a couple of those places there was vey little or no used equipment to be found.
>
> Yes, LA is a wasteland when it comes to decent used gear.
>
> Even postings in the area's craigslist tend to be sparse and asking prices unlrealistic.